# Design routing for Office 365 and Azure Express Route

Tags: azure, routes, office365, azure-virtual-network

Upon reading Azure documentation I still cannot figure out if we can design routing for our Express Route in the way described below.

We are planning to use one proxy server(with one public ip) for all O365 traffic. ( dedicated only for O365 ). Obviously, some of the O365 traffic can and should use ER, but some need to use internet (CDN, DNS, etc).

The goal is to announce proxy server ip toward ER as a /32 and toward internet as /22.

My concern is "assymetric routing" . Can this type of routing create the problem when Microsoft will send traffic to our proxy server via the ER while egress path from our AS lies via internet ?

PS. *I am aware that some of the traffic should not be "proxied" or undergo DPI. Thats a security requirement.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any trouble with the configuration. Given that you are using 2 different address spaces/ CIDRs of Public IP's Provided by your ISP.

The /32 public IP will be advertised to Azure Microsoft Peering over the express route via BGP. Azure, on the other hand, Azure would advertise the Public IP's of the services that you are using. Which can be controlled via Route Filters. Note: The ASN and Public IP needs to be validated for the NAT.

Coming to the Asymmetric aspect that you are concerned about. The o365 services will not propagate the routes to other non-O365 services such as Storage/CDN/DNS.
That said, whatever is coming from the 22 CIDR will be serviced by the non-O355 service and will go over the internet.

The fear for asymmetry occurs when you are consuming the O365 services over the internet instead of consuming them over the express route. Then, there are chances of asymmetry.

Instance 1:
CIDR /22 advertised to Azure over express route and you accidentally consume the O-365 services over the internet. Since, within the O365 cloud the route is populated to use the express route, the return traffic from Azure will come over the ExR circuit. This would be labeled as asymmetric route.

I hope I have clarified your doubt about the architecture. Let me know if you have any further questions as you proceed with this configuration.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply, just to confirm, if my understanding is correct :
If we allocate proxy address (e.g. 7.7.7.7/32 from our existing space 7.7.4.0/22, and advertise in the way I explained, it should not cause any issues with asymmetry because o365 services will not propagate our routes to other non-O365 services such as Storage/CDN/DNS.

Comment: Andy, 7.7.4.0 - 7.7.7.255 is the CIDR that you would be advertising. 
Given the /32 IP also is within the same address range 7.7.7.7. It's possible for an asymmetric route to happen. But, highly unlikely as there are many other IP addresses which you can use to NAT etc...

I would suggest that you explore options:
1. Route Weight/Preference that may be added
2. LPM - Lowest Prefix Match. Azure works on this principle and see if you can incorporate that.
3. Use a new Public IP out of the shared range